# Working examples of Leaflet/Polymaps with GeoJSON tiles generated from Tilestache using Shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, leaflet, polymaps, tilestache

I'm looking to create choropleths using GeoJSON tiles generated from ESRI Shapefiles by TileStache(or similar), in either Leaflet or Polymaps. So far reading and drawing GeoJSON from both Leaflet and Polymaps is really easy, now what I'm looking for are working examples of Tilestache or anything like it generating GeoJSON from ESRI Shapefiles. Looking at the examples on the site, it seems to be pretty straightforward(just some config settings), but I'm wondering if there are any existing implementations out there that I could take a look at to see if I'm heading in the right direction. Google has found me nothing thus far.

Additionally, if anyone knows of a solution for generating Choropleths, or any other input regarding Choropleth generation, that would be fine as well. Really, any input here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Likely too late but here is a good example I found: https://gist.github.com/1716010. I had to draw 30000 features and found that canvas performs quite a bit better than svg.